# How to fix jquery length condition for adding css class

Tags: jquery

I want to give a condition for `li` tag is more than 4 `li` elements, a specific css class (`.extra-margin`) will add `.entry-summary` block element.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  if (jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery').has('li')) {

    if (jQuery('.flex-control-nav li').length > 4) {
      jQuery('.entry-summary').addClass('extra-margin');
    } else {
      jQuery('.entry-summary').addClass('add-margin');
    }

  }
});
```

```css
.add-margin {
  color: red
}

.extra-margin {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery">
  <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>enter code here
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="entry-summary">text here</div>
```

I only get else result after saving this code but when I place this code in the chrome browser console it will work perfectly. How can I achieve this problem?

I am using WordPress 5 and jQuery 1.12.4

Comment: what do you expect i think your sample should work just fine

Comment: How are you adding the `li` items?  Are they there when the page loads (ie before the jquery runs) or do you add them dynamically later (eg through a 3rd party library).  If it works from console but not doc.ready it normally means it's because your running the code later, ie after everything has finished updated.

Comment: I expect to work both conditions if and else. but I get only else condition though have more than 4 <li> elements.

Comment: This <li> element add dynamically. but now have more than 7 <li> elements. and do not get first condition result.

Comment: you should run the check on an event like for example if you need it on load run the check on load.

Comment: Perfect ! it's work 
jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
// code here
});

Comment: You should hook into the method that dynamically loads the `li`s.  As you've not prepared to advise us how that happens, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function() {

  if (jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery').has('li')) {

    if (jQuery('.flex-control-nav li').length > 4) {
      jQuery('.entry-summary').addClass('extra-margin');
    } else {
      jQuery('.entry-summary').addClass('add-margin');
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: It works regardless of what you wrap it in or not wrap at all.

Comment: @zer00ne the problem in the question is that the code is being run before the `li` items have been loaded (as they are loaded "dynamically" but OP doesn't state when or how).  This randomly works for OP most likely due to race conditions (running load functions in order).

Comment: @freedomn-m agreed, I noticed that the OP code in question has jQuery at the top rather than the bottom -- most likely an indication of how OP's real code is written.